# Schemes not determined by morphisms from one object

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I was reading a bit about the functor of points of a scheme, and it was mentioned that there does not exist a scheme $Y$ so that Hom$(Y,X)$ determines the points $X$ for all schemes $X$. This is in contrast to a group whose set $|G|$ is given by $|G| = Hom(\mathbb{Z},G)$, for example.

Is there a simple example/proof no such object $Y$ could exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show that the forgetful functor from schemes to sets is not representable.

Suppose $Y$ represents this functor. Then $Hom_{sch}(Y,Spec(\mathbb{Z}))$ is infinite since $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ has an infinite underlying set. But $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ is a final object in the category of schemes : ther is exactly one morphism $Y\to Spec(\mathbb{Z})$. Contradiction.

Comment: [Aye, aye, Captain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kd71zO6XAC8), well said: +1

Comment: Thanks! Very short and simple. But what about if we restrict to the category of $K$-schemes, for $K$ a field for example? Is the statement still true or is there an easy counterexample?

Comment: Ah then this simple argument doesn't work, you have to use a more theoretical argument : representable functors preserve products, but the forgetful functor to Sets doesn't (the underlying set of a product of $K$-schemes is bigger than the product of the underlying sets, take $\mathbb{A}^2_K = \mathbb{A}^1_K \times_K \mathbb{A}^1_K$ for instance).